# TypeError: element.append is not a function

Tags: javascript

```
html
<div id="btn">$</div>

js
 const btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn"); // сама кнопка

 const popUp = document.createElement("div"); // создаю элемент div
  
 popUp.setAttribute("class", "pop_up"); // добавляю ему нужный мне класс
 popUp.innerHTML = "+1"; // вставляю в него нужный мне текст
 btn.append(popUp); // пытаюсь вставить его в кнопку
```

Как-то так. Я опустил то, как вызывается метод и прочее, т.к. с ними всё в порядке. Скорее всего я совершил очень глупую и очевидную ошибку с добавлением объекта в DOM, но найти её в процессе чтения документации я не смог.

Comment: Вы, наверное, хотели использовать `appendChild()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getElement**S**ByClassName выбирает элемент**Ы**, а не один. Поэтому `btn` - это коллекция элементов.  А в коллекции обращение к элементам происходит по индексу. Поэтому тут не хватает как минимум `[0]`

Comment: Спасибо. Помимо этой, я совершил ещё одну ошибку - зачем-то использовал для btn не getElementById, а getElementsByClassName, когда мне это не нужно.

Comment: @NormalOnly это точно. я даже не посмотрел)